# Make drop-down menu open to the left instead right

Tags: html, css

I want to Make drop-down menu open to the left instead right.
site URL: http://kg.portageplus.org/

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap, add `pull-left` to the class of your dropdown `li`:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles

```
.main-navigation li:hover > ul {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul:before {
    right: 9px;
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul:after {
    right: 11px;
    left: auto;
}
```

Result [image](https://ibb.co/kNQqWd)

Add this style for the sub menu

```
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul {
    right: 100%;
    left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nandita Arora Sharma,
its working for the sub menus now. but still i have the same issue in the sub-sub menu.

with your styles when I put the mouse on the main menu the sub menu opens to the left (many thanks). still I have a sub menu inside the first sub menu but still opens to the right.

Comment: Ok will look into it and let you know